# Motor Control For Overload

Tags: microcontroller, motor, load

I am using PIC 18F45K80 for four phase dc motor control operation. The maximum load current is 30 Amps. If it exceeds 30 Amps, I have to call stop_motor() function in my coding in order to switch off the motor by turning off the low side PWM and high side on/off pulse. What can I do, if I want to run the motor at 30 Amps at higher increasing load (so that the motor continues to draw 30 Amps  for the higher increasing  load for a certain time). If I want to control (decrease) the PWM duty, how can I do it corresponding to the increasing load. Are there other control ways?

Answer (score 1):

Motor load is the same a torque which proportional to motor current.   Without full details, I do not see anyway to escape this.  If the current is limited by PWM, and load increases, this results in a speed reduction until the load is reduced. If it is not reduced, the motor will stop.